# How to eagerly load entities when using filters in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have some XML-based mapping file containing a filter condition for some one-to-many relationship. Before executing a query, the filter is enabled and necessary data bound to it. With the help of some `AutoCloseable`, the filter is disabled for the current session again after the query was executed and some list of entities retrieved. The good thing about filters is that those are applied independently of the current query and one doesn't need to care too much.

But here's the problem: The referenced entities of the elements in that list are lazy-loaded by Hibernate and that only works as expected within the `AutoCloseable`, because afterwards the filter is disabled again and the query results are wrong. OTOH, the filters need to be disabled, because the Hibernate session might be reused for totally unrelated queries as well.

**Is there some way to entirely disable lazy-loading for some session?**

That way I could simply do so when enabling/disabling the filters without the need to care about the mapping file and stuff. Additionally, this is a legacy app and am not sure if Hibernate annotations are recognized at all, none of the ones I applied had any effect on anything.

```xml
<filter-def name      = "mostCurrNonAutoUae"
            condition = "id IN ([...])"
>
  <filter-param   name = "autoRegMails"
                  type = "string"
  />
</filter-def>
```

```xml
<set inverse="true" name="userActivations" access="field">
  <key>
    <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="[...]" />
  <filter name = "mostCurrNonAutoUae" />
</set>
```

In the following example, the results for `Eintrag 1` are wrong, it contains unfiltered elements instead of filtered ones. Which makes sense, because filters have been disabled already, but which wouldn't be a problem without lazy-loading of Hibernate.

```java
    @Override
    public FuserEntity findUserByProfileIdAndUsername(int profileId, String username)
    {
        String stmt = "[...]";

        List<FuserEntity> ret = new ArrayList<>();

        try (FilteringSession session = new FilteringSession())
        {
            Query qry = session.get()
                .createQuery (stmt)
                .setParameter("profileId",  profileId)
                .setParameter("usrName",    username);

            ret = (List<FuserEntity>) qry.list();
            return !ret.isEmpty() ? ret.get(0) : null;
        }
        finally
        {
System.err.println("Liste: "     + ret.toString());
System.err.println("Eintrag 1: " + ret.get(0).getMostCurrNonAutoUae().get().toString());
System.err.println("Eintrag 2: " + ret.get(0).getMostCurrNonAutoUae().get().getFirstName());
        }
```

Thrown exception:

```
2023-05-25 18:18:11 ERROR [...].printException: Unexpected many user activation entries: 3
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unexpected many user activation entries: 3
        at [...].FuserEntity.getMostCurrNonAutoUae(FuserEntity.java:319) ~[classes/:?]
        at [...].FuserDao.findUserByProfileIdAndUsername(FuserDao.java:300) ~[classes/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

[11.7. Dynamic fetching via Hibernate profiles](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-profile)

This seems to be the answer: Fetch profiles are available in XML mapping files, support some name and multiple different entities and associations. So I simply created such a profile with the same name of my created filter and when enabling and disabling filters, one can easily enable/disable the corresponding fetch profiles.

```xml
<fetch-profile name="mostCurrNonAutoUae">
    <fetch  association="userActivations"
            entity="de.riff.platform.shared.model.fuser.FuserEntity"
            style="join"
    />
</fetch-profile>
```

```java
private Session configureSession()
{
    String  name    = FilteringSession.FILTER_NAME;
    Session retVal  = this.getCtx().getHibernateSession();
    
    retVal
        .enableFilter(name)
        .setParameterList("autoRegMails", MailUtil.AUTO_REG_MAIL_EVER);
    retVal.enableFetchProfile(name);

    return retVal;
}
```

Both of the changes result in successful output:

```
Liste: [User admin (BIMAS_DEFAULT)]
Eintrag 1: TABLE: bis_useractivation, OBJID: 12
Eintrag 2: Admin
```

Though, what I don't understand is that the rendered SQL by Hibernate doesn't contain any `JOIN`, but two different selects one after another. So this seems like eager loading instead of lazy, but not using a `JOIN`.

```
2023-05-25 18:29:35 WARN  [...].OnExecute: Checking[...]
Hibernate:
    select
        fuserentit0_.user_id as user_id1_5_,
        [...]
    from
        rs.bis_fuser fuserentit0_
    where
        fuserentit0_.user_group='N'
        and fuserentit0_.LOCATION_ID=?
        and fuserentit0_.username=?
Hibernate:
    select
        useractiva0_.user_id as user_id2_25_1_,
        [...]
    from
        rs.bis_useractivation useractiva0_
    where
        useractiva0_.id IN       ([...])
        and useractiva0_.user_id=?
```